# StackOverflowError when parsing JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON object so I can get a list of book items from the Google Books API. Unfortunately, my project has hit a snag when I tried to extract a JSONArray from the object. It has thrown a java.lang.StackOverflowError exception.

The object seems to have parsed successfully from the response string from the server, however, I'm not sure what exactly happens here when I try to get an array from the object. Any pointers on this are appreciated, especially because I'm a relative newbie to JSON manipulation.

```
static ArrayList<BookItem> getBooks(String queryString){
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String bookJSONString = null;
        mListBooks = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BOOK_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, queryString)
                    .appendQueryParameter(MAX_RESULTS, "10")
                    .build();

            URL requestURL = new URL(builtUri.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) requestURL.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append("\n");
            }

            if(builder.length() == 0) return null;
            bookJSONString = builder.toString();
            Log.d(TAG, bookJSONString);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(bookJSONString);

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return mListBooks;
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONArray.toString()
```

Usually, I'd expect this kind of error to be caused by recursion, but I'm struggling to see where this might occur. The culprit appears to be `JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");` I'm probably parsing this all wrong and the solution is most likely staring me in the face here...

Comment: Can you post the json?

Comment: ya, there might be a problem with your JSON as well. Please post the JSON.

Comment: Yep sure. Here it is: https://pastebin.com/BQWxUdug

Comment: I'll suggest using gson

Answer (score 0):

This way I was able to find an answer to your problem

```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                                    .create();
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(bookJSONString)))
```